# Traer un id de otra tabla sql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con php y necesito apuntar a id de una tabla detalle, el problema es que muestro información de la tabla principal pero mi boton debe apuntar a la información de tabla de talle aqui mi problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El id de la tabla principal es `168` pero en mi boton de detalle debe apuntar a mi id 85 que contiene el detalle de esa tabla.

mi tabla detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como seria la consulta para traer ese `id` de mi tabla detalle a la tabla principal?

Tablas:

```
Entrada: 
id (relacion)
proveedor 
cajas
peso
hora

Detalle:
id
fecha
hora
identrada (relacion)
...
```

Se muestra la información de la tabla `Entrada` pero el link apunta a id del detalle. Ojo! no siempre tiene detalle por lo tanto si se va a traer el id del detalle lo muestre en 0 ¿se puede?

Comment: Para poderte ayudar muestra la consulta con la que llenas la tabla, asi como la estructura de las tablas a relacionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... Por lo que puedo ver seria masomenos

```
SELECT entradas.id as entrada_id, entradas.peso, entradas.cajas, entradas.hora, detalles.id as detalle_id
FROM entradas, detalles 
WHERE entradas.id = detalles.identrada
```

Seria bueno que para este tipo de preguntas explicaras como está modelada tu base de datos para que la comunidad te pueda dar una mejor ayuda

Comment: No puedo estar seguro de como está modelada tu BD... pero por la pregunta parece ser que la tabla entradas y la tabla detalles están relacionadas con cardinalidad de 1 a 1... Para esos casos... es muy común quitar la relación y poner toda la información en una sola tabla (las columnas de las dos tablas)... Talvez esta sugerencia te ayude un poco...

Comment: perfecto, pero... esto lo hago por paso, es decir antes de crear el detalle hago la entrada, por lo tanto detalle aun no se tiene pero debe mostrarse la información principal ¿como hago eso?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
    e.proveedor, 
    e.cajas, 
    e.peso, 
    e.hora, 
    IFNULL(d.id,0) id_detalle 
FROM entrada e 
LEFT JOIN detalle d ON e.id=d.id 
WHERE e.id=168;
```

Explico:

Dado que `LEFT JOIN` indicará que el campo `id` de la tabla `detalle` será `NULL` cuando no haya coincidencias, el uso de `IFNULL` permitirá reemplazarlo en ese caso por el valor `0`.  Esa columna aparecerá en los resultados con el alias `id_detalle`.